# Trigger method in parent uiviewcontroller from uibutton in uiscrollview

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have a uibutton inside a uiScrollview inside a uiviewcontroller. When I click the button I want to be able to call a method in the uiviewcontroller.

I have the following action on my button that calls a method within my uiscrollview:

[categoryButton addTarget:self action:@selector(categoryButtonWasClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

But this just calls a method within my uiscrollview (which I will still keep). How do I then call a method in the viewcontroller??

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enter code here`Try doing something like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol myUIScrollViewProtocol <NSObject>

    -(void)buttonWasPressInScrollView:(id)sender;

@end

@interface MyUIScrollView : UIScrollView

@property (weak, nonatomic)id myDelegate;

@end
```

Create a subclass of UIScrollView and add a delegate then assign your UIViewController as the delegate and implement the "buttonWasPress.." method in it.

Then from the categroryButtonWasClicked method in your uiScrollView:

```
    -(void)categoryButtonWasClicked{
    if ([self.myDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(buttonWasPressInScrollView:)]){
        [self.myDelegate buttonWasPressInScrollView:self];
    }
...
}
```

in your viewController's .h add the following

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <myUIScrollViewProtocol>
```

Comment: How do I assign the viewcontroller as the delegate? Then I put the buttonWasPressInScrollView as a method in the view controller?

Comment: If you have add the ScrollView programatically change itsclass to MyUIScrol... if you've done it in IB then select the scroll view and changes it class to MyUIScrol.... Then in your ViewController simply type [myScrollView setDelegate:self];